# I want make all textboxes on my form to accept only numbers with as little code as possible - c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, keypress

I am making a relatively simple bit of software which has quite a few textboxes and i want a way to only allow numbers in all textboxes in the form with hopefully one piece of code. I am currently using the following code to only allow numbers for one textbox but it means repeating those lines for each textbox.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

The textboxes are also inside a panel incase that makes a difference.

Comment: they don't have to have separate key handlers o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Darek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564092/darek) said, one viable option is to:

> Create a derrived DigitsOnlyTextBox, with the method implemented, and use it in place of TextBoxes

A second option is to simply point each `TextBox` to the same event handler.  For example, in the `Form.Designer.cs`:

```
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBoxNumericOnly_KeyPress);
this.textBox2.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBoxNumericOnly_KeyPress);
this.textBox3.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBoxNumericOnly_KeyPress);
...
```

Then your handler:

```
private void textBoxNumericOnly_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

Assuming you're using Visual Studios and you've already created the event handler the first time (for `textBox1`), you can easily do this all in the designer view of the `Form`:

**A Default Handler**
[image: Adding default event handler in VS]

**Copy Def Handler**
[image: Adding copied event handler in VS]

Comment: okay thanks i understand, but do i add this event handler to the end of the current textbox items in the list or add a line and copy the whole of what you have shown?

Comment: From your code, the event handler is named `textBox1_KeyPress`.  I assume in VS designer mode, you double clicked the `KeyPress` event in the *Properties* tab?  If so, in your `form1.Designer.cs` file, a line was created: `this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyPress);`  Is this how you got your original handler for `textBox`?  I'll explain more according to your responce.

Answer (score 2):

Create a derrived DigitsOnlyTextBox, with the method implemented, and use it in place of TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Forms and not WPF you can use a [MaskedTextBox](http://www.dotnetperls.com/maskedtextbox).

Not sure if you can replicate the capability in WPF, having never used it.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break